# Uniformly convergent subsequnce of equicontinuous and uniformly bounded sequnce fo functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be compact. $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset C(X).$ If  $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is (uniformly) bounded and equicontinuous then  $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

We know uniformly bounded and equicontinuous implies totally bounded(In our problem). Since in a totally bounded space , every sequence has a cauchy subsequnce. We can get uniformly Cauchy subsequnce of  $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Also we have $C(X)$ is complete then every Cauchy sequence converges on $C(X)$.Then we are done.

I found one proof that was pretty long. I am wondering if this idea can work!

Suggestions please!

Comment: The space of equicontinuous functions on a compact space is not totally bounded. For example, the sequence of constant functions $1,2,3,\ldots$ has no Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: If you have proven that in general a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded, then yes, this is fine. But the two proofs together are about the length of the standard "from-scratch" Arzela-Ascoli proof.

Comment: @MattS He specified that they are also uniformly bounded.

Comment: Well yeah the proof is more longe because they're usually showing that "uniformly bounded and equicontinuous implies totally bounded".

Comment: We have proved a theorem in class that equicontinuous and uniformly bounded implies totally bounded. Why can not I apply this to find a Cauchy subsequence?

Comment: @Santosh You can. It's not the usual proof, but it's still perfectly fine, and is actually probably a more instructive proof in terms of ease of generalization.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.